# What does timeout /T > null mean in batch programming

Tags: batch, windows-command-prompt, ms-dos

What does `timeout /T > null` mean in batch programming. I mean I can't seem to figure out what `> null` means here.

Sometimes it is also used for `COPY [source file] [Destination file] > null`

Comment: @Reaces Why the vote to migrate to `unix.stackexchange.com`? It is clearly a Windows question, so it would be even more off-topic there than it is here.

Comment: I am sorry,but I am new to this Forum? But I don't understand how it is off Topic. And why this hostility towards newbies?

Answer (score 2):

It redirects the output of the command before the `>` to the `null` device which is effectively a digital black hole that takes the input and just forgets it. The effect is that the program doesn't show any messages.

Comment: Thank you Sven your answer helped me through this Problem.